# How to manage library dependency for Google Cloud Library

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

My main question is: is there any way to manage GCP libraries and Google SDK effectively so dependencies problems do not occur?
Currently I have the following GCP libraries on python:

```
google-api-core==1.32.0
google-apitools==0.5.32
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.8.1
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.4
google-cloud-storage==1.14.0
google-cloud-vision==0.36.0
google-compute-engine==2.8.13
google-cloud-dataproc==4.0.3
google-api-python-client==2.52.0
google-crc32c==1.3.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.3
```

I would like toi nstall google-cloud-bigquery-reservation==1.6.3
However, after I install it using `pip install` and try to use it, the following error will occur. From the stack it looks like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/data_creation_scripts/make_model_external_data.py", line 12, in <module>
    from definition.phase_data_generator import ModelExternalDataGenerator
  File "/home/batch/dsp-content-ad-model/releases/20221020101735Z/src/python/definition/phase_data_generator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dataset_module.base_dataset import AbstractDataSet
  File "/home/batch/dsp-content-ad-model/releases/20221020101735Z/src/python/dataset_module/base_dataset.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bq_extract_module.bq_table_creator import BqTableCreatorFactory
  File "/home/batch/dsp-content-ad-model/releases/20221020101735Z/src/python/bq_extract_module/bq_table_creator.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utils.bq_query_executor import BqExecutorFactory
  File "/home/batch/dsp-content-ad-model/releases/20221020101735Z/src/python/utils/bq_query_executor.py", line 13, in <module>
    from utils import bq_utils
  File "/home/batch/dsp-content-ad-model/releases/20221020101735Z/src/python/utils/bq_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from utils.flex_slots import FlexSlotUtil
  File "/home/batch/dsp-content-ad-model/releases/20221020101735Z/src/python/utils/flex_slots.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery_reservation_v1 import *
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_reservation_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .services.reservation_service import (
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_reservation_v1/services/reservation_service/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .async_client import ReservationServiceAsyncClient
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_reservation_v1/services/reservation_service/async_client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery_reservation_v1.services.reservation_service import pagers
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_reservation_v1/services/reservation_service/pagers.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery_reservation_v1.types import reservation
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_reservation_v1/types/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .reservation import (
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_reservation_v1/types/reservation.py", line 60, in <module>
    class Reservation(proto.Message):
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 222, in __new__
    field=[i.descriptor for i in fields],
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 222, in <listcomp>
    field=[i.descriptor for i in fields],
  File "/home/batch/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/proto/fields.py", line 113, in descriptor
    proto3_optional=self.optional,
ValueError: Protocol message FieldDescriptorProto has no "proto3_optional" field.
```

Comment: Are you currently under the virtual environment on Cloud Shell?

Comment: I am working with conda on a Linux's terminal. Not with Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for installing a virtual environment on your Cloud Shell, in case you are not using it:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
```

Afterwards, install `google-cloud-bigquery-reservation==1.6.3`.

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery-reservation==1.6.3
```

Here is the result of my replication:

[image]

---

If you are still encountering the same error, check your `protobuf` and make sure that you have the latest version or atleast `protobuf==3.19.0` version.

Just follow me up with a comment regarding the outcome of your case.